# c++&python close and open files in different dll

Tags: python, c++, dll, ctypes

The situation is simple. I open file in one DLL (DLL1) and close it in another (DLL2). I invoke both DLLs one after another in python script, the code is as following:

```
from ctypes import *

DLLFP1=r"C:\Workspaces\CPP\Test\build\files1.dll"
DLLFP2=r"C:\Workspaces\CPP\Test\build\files2.dll"
DLL1=cdll.LoadLibrary(DLLFP1)
DLL2=cdll.LoadLibrary(DLLFP2)

cppobj=c_void_p()
DLL1.open( byref(cppobj) )

DLL2.close(cppobj)
```

DLL1 code:

```
#define DLLEXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

DLLEXPORT void open(ofstream* &f){
  f = new ofstream();
  string FP("c:\\teest.log");
  f->open(FP);
}
```

and DLL2 code:

```
#define DLLEXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

DLLEXPORT void close(ofstream* f){
  f->close();
}
```

In the result I have "access violation writing". I also can normally write text to file from DLL2 and if I move close function to DLL1 it works fine. I use intel compiler. OS is Windows7.

The question is what is wrong? What is the right way to share file between DLLs?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Related: [Did C++11 address concerns passing std lib objects between dynamic/shared library boundaries?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/176681/did-c11-address-concerns-passing-std-lib-objects-between-dynamic-shared-librar)

Comment: Try to link the two dlls with dynamic C runtime, with MS's cl.exe it's `/MD' switch

Comment: I've tried, unfortunately, it doesn't help.

Comment: It should write the stream address to the dereferenced pointer, e.g. `*f = new ofstream();`. As is all your doing is modifying the local variable `f`.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related unless *DLL1* and *DLL2* are built for the same runtime: [Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx)

> When you pass C Run-time (CRT) objects such as file handles, locales,
>   and environment variables into or out of a DLL (function calls across
>   the DLL boundary), unexpected behavior can occur if the DLL, as well
>   as the files calling into the DLL, use different copies of the CRT
>   libraries.